# Spark Hbase connection issue

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, apache-spark-sql, hortonworks-data-platform

Hitting with followiong error while i am trying to connect the hbase through spark(using `newhadoopAPIRDD`) in HDP 2.4.2.Already tried increasing the RPC time in hbase site xml file,still getting the same. any idea how to fix ?

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed after attempts=36, exceptions:
Wed Nov 16 14:59:36 IST 2016, null, java.net.SocketTimeoutException: callTimeout=60000, callDuration=71216: row 'scores,,00000000000000' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=hklvadcnc06.hk.standardchartered.com,16020,1478491683763, seqNum=0

   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.throwEnrichedException(RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.java:271)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:195)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:59)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:200)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.call(ClientScanner.java:320)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.nextScanner(ClientScanner.java:295)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.initializeScannerInConstruction(ClientScanner.java:160)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.<init>(ClientScanner.java:155)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.getScanner(HTable.java:821)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner.metaScan(MetaScanner.java:193)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner.metaScan(MetaScanner.java:89)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner.allTableRegions(MetaScanner.java:324)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HRegionLocator.getAllRegionLocations(HRegionLocator.java:88)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.RegionSizeCalculator.init(RegionSizeCalculator.java:94)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.RegionSizeCalculator.<init>(RegionSizeCalculator.java:81)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase.getSplits(TableInputFormatBase.java:256)
   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat.getSplits(TableInputFormat.java:237)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.getPartitions(NewHadoopRDD.scala:120)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
   at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
   at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1929)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1157)
   at scb.Hbasetest$.main(Hbasetest.scala:85)
   at scb.Hbasetest.main(Hbasetest.scala)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: callTimeout=60000, callDuration=71216: row 'scores,,00000000000000' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=hklvadcnc06.hk.standardchartered.com,16020,1478491683763, seqNum=0
       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:159)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ResultBoundedCompletionService$QueueingFuture.run(ResultBoundedCompletionService.java:64)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.ConnectionClosingException: Call to hklvadcnc06.hk.standardchartered.com/10.20.235.13:16020 failed on local exception: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.ConnectionClosingException: Connection to hklvadcnc06.hk.standardchartered.com/10.20.235.13:16020 is closing. Call id=9, waitTime=171
       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.wrapException(RpcClientImpl.java:1281)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.call(RpcClientImpl.java:1252)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:213)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:287)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$BlockingStub.scan(ClientProtos.java:32651)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.openScanner(ScannerCallable.java:372)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:199)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:62)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:200)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas$RetryingRPC.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:346)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas$RetryingRPC.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:320)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:126)
       ... 4 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.ConnectionClosingException: Connection to hklvadcnc06.hk.standardchartered.com/10.20.235.13:16020 is closing. Call id=9, waitTime=171
       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.cleanupCalls(RpcClientImpl.java:1078)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.close(RpcClientImpl.java:879)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.run(RpcClientImpl.java:604)
16/11/16 14:59:36 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
```

Comment: Smells like the HBase client lib cannot find its `hbase-site.xml` and tries to guess where ZK is located. And misses. Make sure the "driver extraClasspath" contains *directory* `/etc/hbase/conf`

Comment: i tired adding the hbase/conf as you mentioned ...still its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added the hbase-conf path in hadoop classpath and the issue has been resolved .

Thanks!

Comment: how to add hbase-conf path in hadoop classpath?

Answer (score 0):

Though a bit different context but I faced a **similar** type of exception while connecting **hive with hbase**.
Guess what! My hbase table's column mapping was mis-configure.
After I configured hbase tables's columns properly(Metadata of the table),the issue vanished.

```
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES("hbase.columns.mapping" = "personal data:,:key")
```